# Docker: Client Server Program each running as a Container Not Able to Communicate with each Other Using POSIX Socket API

Tags: docker

Issue Description with Steps to Reproduce:
I have a Server program written in C++ ,using posix Socket API. The Dockerfile used for building the Server image is:

```
$ cat Dockerfile
FROM gcc:4.9
WORKDIR /home/vikrana
COPY . .
EXPOSE 1001
RUN g++ -o testcplusplus testprogram.cpp
ENV PATH /home/vikrana:$PATH
ENTRYPOINT ["testcplusplus", "1001"]
```

Below is the server program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <errno.h>


using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int sockfd, newsockfd, portno;
  socklen_t clilen;
  char buffer[256];
  struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;
  int n;
  if(const char* env_p = std::getenv("PATH"))
      std::cout << "Your PATH is: " << env_p << '\n';
  if(argc < 2)
  {
      cout<<"Number of arguments not correct\n";
      exit(1);
  }
  cout<<argv[1]<<"\n";
  cout<<"Creating socket\n";
  struct protoent *proto;
  proto = getprotobyname("tcp");
  sockfd=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, proto->p_proto);
  cout<<"Socket created successfully\n";

  portno=atoi(argv[1]);
  serv_addr.sin_family=AF_INET;
  serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr("0.0.0.0");
  cout<<"Port No:"<<portno<<"\n";
  serv_addr.sin_port=htons(portno);
  cout<<"Starting binding socket to a port\n";
  if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr,
            sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)
  {
      cout<<"Error while binding\n";
      exit(1);
  }
  cout<<"Bind is successful\n";
  cout<<"Listening to port\n";
  int x =listen(sockfd,5);
  if(x<0)
  {
   cout<<"Error on listening to port 1001\n";
   cout<<errno<<"\n";
   cout<<strerror(errno)<<"\n";
   close(sockfd);
   exit(1);
 }
 clilen=sizeof(cli_addr);
 cout<<"Accepting connection\n";
 newsockfd=accept(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *)&cli_addr,&clilen);
 if(newsockfd <0)
 {
    cout<<"Error while accepting a new connection\n";
    close(sockfd);
    exit(1);
 }
 cout<<"Accepted the connection\n";
 while(true)
 {
    memset(&buffer,0,sizeof(buffer));
    cout<<"Reading from socket to buffer\n";
    n=read(newsockfd,buffer,255);
    if(n<0)
    {
        cout<<"Erro reading from socket\n";
        close(sockfd);
        close(newsockfd);
        exit(1);
    }
    cout<<"Message received to the server:"<<buffer<<"\n";
    n=write(newsockfd,"I got your message\n",19);
    if(n<0)
    {
       cout<<"Error writing into socket\n";
       close(sockfd);
       close(newsockfd);
       exit(1);
    }
  }
 close(sockfd);
 close(newsockfd);
 return 0;
 }
```

Following is the Docker command I am using to run my server program in the container:

```
 $ docker run --net=user_def_nw -ti -P --name server1 my-server-app
```

On running above command the container gets attached with user_def_nw and an IP address is assigned to the container.

On the other hand following are the details of my Client program written in C++ using posix Socket API.
DockerFile to create client image:

```
$ cat Dockerfile
FROM gcc:4.9
WORKDIR /home/vikrana
COPY . .
RUN g++ -o testcplusplus testclientprogram.cpp
ENV PATH /home/vikrana:$PATH
ENTRYPOINT ["testcplusplus", "0.0.0.0", "1001"]
```

Below is the code for the client program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <netdb.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int sockfd, newsockfd, portno;
  struct sockaddr_in server;
  char message[256], server_reply[2000];
  if(const char* env_p = std::getenv("PATH"))
          std::cout << "Your PATH is: " << env_p << '\n';
  struct protoent *proto;
  proto = getprotobyname("tcp");
  sockfd=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, proto->p_proto);
  cout<<"socket created\n";

  cout<<argv[1]<<"\n";
  cout<<argv[2]<<"\n";
  portno=atoi(argv[2]);
  cout<<portno<<"\n";
  server.sin_family=AF_INET;
  server.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr(argv[1]);
  server.sin_port=htons(portno);
  memset(server.sin_zero, '\0', sizeof server.sin_zero);

  cout<<"connecting to server\n";
   int x =connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&server, sizeof(server));
   cout<<"Connect Return Code:"<<x<<"\n";
  if(x<0)
  {
      cout<<"Connect Failed\n";
      cout<<errno<<"\n";
      cout<<strerror(errno)<<"\n";
      exit(1);
  }
  cout<<"Connected\n";
  while(1)
  {
      cout<<"Enter Message:";
      cin>>message;

      if(send(sockfd,message,strlen(message),0) < 0)
      {
          cout<<"Send Failed\n";
          exit(1);
      }
      sleep(2);

      if(recv(sockfd,server_reply,2000,0) < 0)
      {
         cout<<"Recv Failed\n";
         break;
      }

      cout<<"Server Reply:"<<server_reply<<"\n";
     }
  close(sockfd);
   return 0;
 }
```

Following is the Docker command I am using to run my client program in the container:

```
 $ docker run --net=user_def_nw -ti --name cli1 my-client-app
```

On running the above command it is noticed Client is not able to connect to the server listening at port 1001.

The error code return my the connect API is "111" which means, connection refused.

My understanding is since both the containers namely server1 and cli1 are attached to the same user defined network "user_def_nw" bridge network, they should be able to communicate with each other over Socket. But here connect API itself is failing to establish connection with the Server.

Also, I tried the following
1) I ran my client server program as a normal process in a given Linux system, it works perfectly fine.

2) I made my base image as ubuntu and top of it installed g++ compiler, and then ran my client and server program as independent containers, still the same error as reported above I am getting.

Please help me in resolving this issue.

Answer (score 0):

In a user defined network, you can connect two containers by referring their container name. In your client app dockerfile, try to replace 0.0.0.0 with server1.

Comment: I replaced "0.0.0.0" with server1 in my client app dockerfile. Then I restarted my client app again . This time the error code set by the "connect" Socket API was 101 which means, "Network is unreachable".

Comment: Did you rebuild the docker image?

Comment: Yes, I have rebuild my client image after making the changes as suggested by you.

Comment: Any further suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are connecting with wrong IP address from client.
Run your server container

Now check the actual server's container IP address using ***docker network inspect bridge*** command

Now try to connect the client using this IP address.

I think docker Gateway will have 172.17.0.1, and if u run server next u may get 172.17.0.2 as server's IP.

Hope it solves ur problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can access containers in the same network via DNS entries (one for each container name).

Here’s an example to explain. In your case you will configure the client container to connect to the server DNS entry server (similar to how myserver is used below).

```
$ docker network create javaapp
451905b63038719be32c3029dd229d02260fdc6f5fcca136c063556d3f3714d4

$ docker run -d --net javaapp --name myserver nginx
4b8c235789b2b262190f39d1ca2495304ca4ffc84321a127ac1bb9a0b748c717

$ docker run --net javaapp nathanleclaire/curl curl myserver:80
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:05 --:--:--     0



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>`enter code here`
<head>
<title>Welcome to nginx!</title>
<style>
    body {
        width: 35em;
        margin: 0 auto;
        font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
```